# why there is a need of hadoop commands in Pseudo-distributed mode?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

It might be a stupid question but I needed to know.

For example: Why do we need hadoop fs -ls command to list files? Instead why can't just ls be used?

If in pseudo-distributed mode, is that case part of filesystem is given to hadoop file system that is only accessible to hadoop namenode daemon...this is my guess. Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

`ls` will list all file spaces available to your computer

You can set the `fs.defaultFS` property to be `file:///`, the default, then both will act the same, but this is not considered pseudodistributed mode.

Pseudodistributed node requires that you specify a list of datanode and namenode volumes on each respective system in the cluster, and `hdfs dfs` commands will only list those files that are known by the namenode.

And its called pseudodistributed only because it's a single node. Once you have that working, adding another node should be straightforward given appropriate networking connections